# Controller used to handle tracking numbers on order shipments

Tags: magento-1.7, shipment-tracking, admin-controller

I can't seem to find the controller responsible for the handling of tracking numbers on order shipments (in the admin). I have an issue where entering a tracking number, then hit Save (supposedly creating a shipment) ends with a 404.

So I wanted to trace where the problem could happen. What I've tried is to `die;` in the `saveAction()` of `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\Order\ShipmentController.php`. Unfortunately, it looks like the action is never called because I still get my 404, and no shipment is created.

Does someone have the knowledge of what is wrong with that or where exactly the tracking number handling is supposed to happen?

Comment: Did you check to see if you have any extensions that are controlling this process. It is possible that one of them has overwritten or extended the core.

Comment: I've tried it by replacing a bit of code in the standard router (I think I had found a topic on that from Alan Storm) which theoretically allowed to see which routes had been matched. But it was unsuccessful as I didn't manage to find the controller responsible for that behaviour.

Comment: If you have extensions try disabling all of them (or any that could possibly effect this functionality) and see if it fixes the problem. If it starts working again then one of your extensions is breaking it and you will just need to find which one.

Comment: You may also need a patch from Magento check on https://www.magereport.com/ also make sure you have the USPS patches

Comment: I've found a workaround, now I'm using a custom script to import tracking numbers, it's easier to handle this way and I don't have to rely on the tons of shipping extensions with each their own handling method. I just wanted to know where exactly the tracking number handling occurs and where. Thanks for your insights though.